# console says cant read charCodeAt property

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, character, fromcharcode

```
<script> 
var str=prompt('enter');
var a= str.split('');
for (j=0; j<str.length; j++){
for(i=j; i<str.length; i++)
{
  if(a[i].charCodeAt(0) > a[i+1].charCodeAt(0))
    {
      var b= a[i];
      a[i]=a[i+1];
      a[i+1]=b;
    }
}
}

     str=a.join('');
    document.write(str);

</script>
```

I know that sort method is more efficient but can somebody please tell whats wrong here. I want to sort the string but it shows cannt read charCodeAt property. Thank you;

Comment: `a[i+1]` will be out of bound for last index index of array, probably you want to use `i < str.length - 1`

Comment: that wont get the correct output. I tried that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have out of bounds problem. It is happens when you try to compare charCodeAt of first character to second one, when second is doesn't exists (e.g. in the end of array you have no more chars to compare with).

As we discussed in comments, you need just to sort your string by letters' charCodeAt, so you can use this code to sort your string:

```js
function bubbleSort(ar) {
  for (var i = (ar.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      if (ar[j-1] > ar[j]) {
        var temp = ar[j-1];
        ar[j-1] = ar[j];
        ar[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
  return ar;
}

function sortString(input) {
  return bubbleSort(
    input
      .split('')
      .map(function(char) {
        return char.charCodeAt(0)
      })
  ).map(function(charCode) {
    return String.fromCharCode(charCode);
  }).join('');
}

console.log(sortString('abcabcabc')); // => "aaabbbccc"
console.log(sortString('вбавбавба')); // => "ааабббввв"
```

Reference: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Sorting%20Algorithms/sorting.html

Comment: That's what i tried first. It requires one more iteration to get the output correct.

Comment: @Harisvc, can you please explain how your algorithm actually should works, so I can adjust my answer for you?

Comment: just try the code you gave with an example. its not completely sorting. Thank you for responding though.

Comment: @Harisvc, do you want to sort your string? There's already exist method for it with array sort, I can create example.

Comment: I need to sort without using the method sort.

Comment: I adjusted it for you, also you can check reference for the algorithm information.